# Autnomous transaction SQL server2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers

I want to update a column on the inserted row with a trigger (SQL server):
example:
I have a table employee (firstname, lastname, score1, score2, total)
Iwant to create a trigger that after insert a new row (firstname, lastname, score1, score2) row into the table, set the score1+score2 value to the column total of the same inserted row

Comment: Ok, what part of creating an after-insert trigger are you having an issue with? What have you tried so far? Can you post your code?

Comment: You might be better of with a calculated column. Avoid triggers if possible. Unless it's a tutorial or homework where they are guaranteed to ask for dumb things

Comment: i know that i should avoid trigger and i already wordked it with a calculated column,but i want to do this with a trigger.i have problem with mutating table when i want to update the inserted row.do you think that it is dumb?

Comment: Its not dumb to practice, experiment and learn. It _is_ dumb to use a trigger if you don't have to. It is also dumb to not explain the actual problem that you are having. If you can't explain it no one can help. If you get an error post it.